# ConnectionStrings Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-code

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio Code com a extensão mssql no linux, preciso pregar Connection Strings de um banco de dados que já criei, mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: O que exatamente você não está conseguindo?

Comment: No curso que estou fazendo, o cara está visual studio, ele seleciona o banco de dados, e tecla "f4", abre as propriedades, e la ele localiza o campo "Connection Strings", e copia o texto. Não estou conseguindo acessar esse campo pelo visual studio code.

Comment: Bro, não conheço nenhuma extensão, creio que terás que montar string de conexão na mão.

Comment: Provavelmente é a mesma pergunta que ele fez aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/368553/35358