# Aplicação mvc com visual studio code, Connection Strings

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, connectionstring

Estou utilizando o Visual Studio Code com a extensão `mssql` no linux e preciso pegar a `Connection String` de um banco de dados que já criei, mas não estou conseguindo.

O professor do curso que estou fazendo esta usando o visual studio e fez da seguinte maneira:

[image: propiedas]

Depois que ele copia esse trecho ele usa aqui:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu só preciso pegar esse texto do `Connection Strings` para meu código funcionar.

Comment: Bem vindo Eduardo Carvalho. Ao invés de imagens, procure postar os trechos de códigos. Se possível mostre também onde pretende iniciar seu contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não especificou na pergunta, segue a forma que você poderia fazer no **Startup.cs**:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //...

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });

        //Restante do método Configuration abaixo......
    }

    //Restante da classe Startup abaixo......
    //.........
    //.........
}
```

### **Veja um exemplo completo aqui.**

### **Documentação da microsoft sobre strings de conexão.**

Comment: Esse código da imagem também gera as tabelas do banco de dados. Por isso acho que tem que ser dessa maneira.

Comment: @EduardoCarvalho o EF que gera as tabelas no BD. Nas imagens da sua pergunta tem apenas uma tela de propriedades que não consegui reconhecer devido a qualidade dela e um arquivo de configuração json.